# how to display a color image stored in a ROM in vhdl?

Tags: screen, vhdl, rom

I am doing a project with xilinx vivado using zybo700, and one of the subtask is to display an image on a touch screen 480*272. I use a rom to store the rgb information of the image and want to display on the screen but I don't know how exactly it should be done, can someone gives me some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by reading the datasheet for the LCD display.

Design an interface between your ROM and that display, according to the requirements in that datasheet.

Write a testbench for that interface, and simulate until it generates the waveforms needed by the LCD display (these are in the datasheet).

When it passes simulation tests, synthesise it, and generate a bitfile which you can download into the FPGA.

Run it and see what happens.